# Karma tests randomly restart and "double" iframe in Edge

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, angular-test

I have a suite of Karma/Jasmine tests for my Angular 7 app.  All my tests pass in Chrome and Firefox, but when I run them in Edge it will run for a little bit and then sometimes it will randomly reload the page and start over, and sometimes it will load karma again into the iframe, thus "doubling" it.

Here's what it looks like

[image: double karma tests]

However, when I click the "Debug" button it opens a new tab and all the tests run fine in there with no failures.

[image: success debug karma tests]

And here's what my console output looks like.  you can see it runs a few tests and then just restarts them

[image]

---

### What is going on here?

Why would it behave this way in Edge when there are no test failures?

Comment: What happens if you tell Karma to just run the tests once. Right now, I assume you're using the watch feature.

Comment: I turned off `restartOnFileChange` and the same thing happens.  When I turn off `autoWatch` nothing happens, no test are run at all.  Yes there are navigation tests, but all of those are mocked to avoid this issue happening. And again, **all** tests pass in other browsers and in the Karma debug view in Edge.

Comment: I suspect this is an Edge support issue with your source code. For whatever reason the restarting is a by product of a bug in your code. I can't find any open issues for Karma that come close to this. Start narrowing down which tests reproduce the problem. The alternative is to just give up on Edge. No one here will blame you.

Comment: ha, well ok then.  I suppose I'll just go through and `fdescribe` each suite until I find what causes it.  I suspect you are right, but only time will tell...

Comment: You might want to try adding more polyfills first. The ones recommended aren't always enough. If you look in the `node_modules` package for the polyfills. You'll see that there are many more that can be added. Try adding all of them and see if that fixes it, then narrow now which ones are needed.

Comment: @cgTag Wouldn't I see failed tests or console errors when I run the tests in the debug view if that were the case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, and it turned out to be a navigation issue.

I had a component with a `href="#"` in the template like this: `<a href="#" (click)="doSomething($event)">` and then handled like this:

```js
doSomething($event: Event): void {
  $event.preventDefault();
  someService.whatever();
}
```

in my test I had something like this

```js
it('should call the doSomething() method when a link is clicked', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'doSomething');

    const link: HTMLAnchorElement = debugEl.query(By.css('a')).nativeElement;
    link.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

but this caused Edge (and not other browsers for some reason) to attempt to navigate to the `#` which caused the tests to reload.  The solution was to just add `.and.callThrough()` so that the component can just run the `$event.preventDefault()` to prevent the navigation in the tests.

So, the above test now just looks like this

```js
it('should call the doSomething() method when a link is clicked', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'doSomething').and.callThrough(); //call through to run preventDefault() on the click event

    const link: HTMLAnchorElement = debugEl.query(By.css('a')).nativeElement;
    link.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(component.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```